# Use a random in a static class

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a class in my project to create a "global method" that can be executed from other forms. I'm not sure if this is bad practice, but because it's a `static class`, I can not (easily) use a `Random` in it. My code without declaring a random is as follows.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DefaultNamespace;

namespace LevelGenerator
{
    public static class LevelGen
    {
        static int levelIndex = 0;
        static DefaultNamespace.frmSplashScreen myMenu = new DefaultNamespace.frmSplashScreen();

        public static void NewLevel()
        {
            levelIndex = rnd.Next(1, 6);
```

In short, I need a method that can be called from anywhere - this is why I used a `static class` - but it also needs to have a `Random`. I would imagine there are many ways to do this.

Comment: You don't have to use one `Random`, the problem is creating it over and over again in a tight loop. There's nothing wrong with using it in a static class.

Comment: I'd like to know who told you to only use one `Random` instance throughout a project. IMO that's horrible advice.

Comment: Perhaps just one `Random` per file in the project. Either way, I can't simply declare it as `Random rnd = new Random();` in the static class.

Comment: I would also suggest seeding Random, e.g. Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()) to prevent the same values each time the app is run.

Comment: `Random` is not safe to use from multiple threads, which can happen if you use it in a static method.  You'll need to synchronize access to it in such cases.

Comment: @Servy Or use [`new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random())`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that every thread gets its own copy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) to initialize class (static) variables.  Or for that matter, you can simply use a combined initialization & declaration statement.

*So either explicit:*

```
namespace LevelGenerator {
    public static class LevelGen {
        static Random random;

        static LevelGen() {
            random = new Random();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

*or implicit:*

```
namespace LevelGenerator {
    public static class LevelGen {
        static Random random = new Random();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest seeding `Random`, e.g. `Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())` to prevent the same values each time the app is run.

Comment: @roryap, I suppose I should just test this quickly myself, but isn't Random seeded by the system time by default?

Comment: Maybe you're right.  But, in that case, if you're running it quickly enough, it will still get the same seed.  Computers are fast!

Comment: Visual Studio yields an error "The type or namespace name `Random` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?". Am I missing a `using` line to import the Random class or something?

Comment: @Gnome that means you need a `using System;` at the top of your file

Comment: Aha, I put everything I needed but that one line. Great!

Comment: @roryap I doubt that this is likely to happen if computers are as [precise](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900(v=vs.85).aspx) as fast! Also the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) states: "Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a **time-dependent** default seed value."

Comment: Well, I wouldn't take the gamble.  Not if you want to write robust software.

Comment: @roryap it is dependent on the time (I guess it's the *system* time not the elapsed time while starting up the application)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman The precision of the system time is typically in the tens of milliseconds range.

Comment: @roryap, I don't understand under what circumstances you think two `Random` instances will be created in this code.  Wouldn't you need two instances for them to have "the same seed"?  If you mean running the program twice in a row will yield two runs with the same seed, I suppose that is possible, but I don't consider that a likely scenario: the user would have to be starting the two runs programmatically, as there's no way a user could execute two commands on the command line in less time than the resolution of the system clock.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman -- And why would you want to gamble on what the precision of the system clock is when you can virtually guarantee uniqueness using GUID?

Comment: @adv12 exactly that. And relying on ``Guid.newGuid().GetHashCode()`` is just using a rng to create a rng. GUID does **NOT** guarantee uniqueness. But two same values are very unlikely, though.

Comment: @adv12 -- That's *exactly* what I mean: something programmatically running the executable.  You can't rule it out.  Our job is to write robust software, not to dictate or guarantee how it will be used.  That is out of our control

Comment: @adv12 -- Besides, given two methods, one which is "iffy" at best, the other which is virtually guaranteed to be correct... why are you even arguing about it?

Comment: @roryap, fair enough.

Comment: oh god, this discussion. If you're so concerned about true randomness, connect your program to https://www.RANDOM.ORG/ and roll a truly random value.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman -- This is a fair discussion among conscientious developers.  What's the problem?  You either care about doing your best, or you don't.  This industry is full of people in the latter camp, and it's a shame.  Good software is hard to produce, and it behooves you to take every possible step to get it right.

Comment: @roryap True, but in most scenarios ``new Random()`` is fine. And if you need further randomness, the GUID or webservice (RANDOM.ORG) approach are to prefer.

Answer (score 3):

The same way you create your myMenu variable

```
static DefaultNameSpace.frmSplashScreen myMenu = new DefaultNameSpace.frmSplashScreen();
```

you can create rnd variable as well

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I tried at first but it must have been from not including `using System;` great.

Comment: usually, when you see something underlined in VS, you can press Ctrl+. and VS will offer you solutions.. in this case, it would show you options to insert that using for you, or add the namespace. IIRC it is called smart tags

Comment: @JiriP. In Visual Studio, it's called [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hcw1s69b.aspx)

Comment: I knew about IntelliSense but `Ctrl` + `.` is news to me! thanks

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman actually, IntelliSense is something else, like code completion and parameter info (well, see at your link :) ). What I meant is really called [Smart tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj153218.aspx#BKMK_Writing)

Comment: @JiriP. haha, thanks, I learned something :D smart tags are the underlines, and the menu is the intellisense, right?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I would rather say it is difference between `Ctrl+.` and `Ctrl+Space`

Comment: @JiriP. unless someone changes the hotkeys :P

Answer (score 2):

Since [`System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class, you can have a field or property of type `Random`

```
public static Random Rng;
```

From there, you can either initialize inline, from a static constructor, or require a call to an initialize function. The last I would recommend if you wish to collect a seed value from a user, so I will demonstrate below

```
private static bool _randomReady = false;
public static Random Rng;

public static void SeedRandom(int seed)
{
    // By not checking random ready here you will be able to reset the random later
    Rng = new Random(seed);
    _randomReady = true;
}
public static void NewLevel()
{
    // By checking random ready, you can throw a more useful exception than NullReferenceException
    if(!_randomReady)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Random Number Generation is not ready - call SeedRandom first!");
    levelIndex = Rng.Next(1, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instance management such as:

```
public class MyRandom
{
    static Random random;
    public static Random Random
    {
        get
        {
            if (random == null)
                random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Milliseconds)
            return random;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use: `int i = MyRandom.Random.Next()`